# Is it possible to find the Jewel of Dirgest?

Tags: diablo-iii

Covetous Shen is looking for a particular jewel:

> The jewel contains a... powerful creature named Dirgest. He was trapped within it for terrible crimes against his people. [...] Now a flaw has developed in the jewel. Through it, Dirgest can consume the holder's life. I intend to seal his prison, trapping him in it forever.

Most of the other follower/artisan quests come to some kind of resolution (even if it is pretty much non-interactive and tangential to the game), but I don't remember this one ever going anywhere.  Is there more dialog with Shen that I haven't seen where he achieves his goal?

If this isn't resolved through dialog, does Dirgest's jewel exist within the game?  If so, what happens if you manage to find it?  Is Dirgest at all important in the overall lore of the series, or is he just a macguffin for Shen to be seeking?

Comment: It'll show up in the Diablo 3 expansion when we chase after Adria to save Leah's soul. Also, a shapeshifter class in the spirit of the druid in D2. *sage nod*.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, were you just speculating, or was this content they intended on adding to the expansion?

Comment: @Timelord64 Merely speculating! But here's hoping we'll see it in the next xpac!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reaper of Souls has brought with it the ability to find the Jewel of Dirgest, though not as you might expect.

Act V takes you to Pandamonium, where you venture into Westmarch. Covetous Shen may give you a quest that takes you into the Unearthed Ruins, where the Jewel of Dirgest should rest.

While Dirgest has made an escape, shattering the jewel, his minion Vekriss lies in wait. Defeating him releases Liria's soul, and provides a cryptic conclusion to the story of The Jewel of Dirgest, as well as the true origins of Shen.

> **Liria:** Zei? Is that you?
>
> **Shen:** Zei is gone and no more. He is a legend and a myth. The man who stands before you is but a simple jeweler. I have seen the years, And I have loved and lost, and I have grieved and wept.
>
> **Liria:** Whoever you are, you have freed me, and I am happy to have looked upon your face.
>
> **Shen:** And I am filled with joy to have seen yours once again. Farewell, and go upon this last journey.

Answer (score 3):

No. This is just a story being spun by Shen to allow for continued conversation and dialog with him. It is not an item you can find in game.

Comment: This is now inaccurate, as the jewel was added with the Reaper of Souls expansion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do find it, though only in  an added quest in Reaper of Souls. It's broken, though, and you slay the Demon who freed Dirgest. You actually get some confirmation that Shen's Zei, as well! And, sorry. You get the Crusader in ROS, not a shapeshifter. :P